# bubble sort implementation in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

the code below is used to implement bubble sort. why is template used in this case? and what is the purpose of `swapped` variabe. even if i remove `swapped` variable and `swapped condition` from loop code still works fine

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename RandomAccessIterator>
void bubble_sort(RandomAccessIterator begin, RandomAccessIterator end) {
  bool swapped = true;
  while (begin != end-- && swapped) {
    swapped = false;
    for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
      if (*(i + 1) < *i) {
        std::iter_swap(i, i + 1);
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int a[] = {100, 2, 56, 200, -52, 3, 99, 33, 177, -199};
  bubble_sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
  copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

ANOTHER IMPLEMENTATION:

```
template<typename Iterator>
 void bubbleSort(Iterator first, Iterator last)
 {
     Iterator i, j;
     for (i = first; i != last; i++)
         for (j = first; j < i; j++)
             if (*i < *j)
                 std::iter_swap(i, j); // or std::swap(*i, *j);
 }
```

Comment: The `swapped` variable makes the code run faster. Basically it tests if there was any two values exchanged in a run. If there was none, there is no need to continue checking. To check this, create a long, already sorted, vector and run and time it with and without the `swapped` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different containers have their own iterator types. For example for one-dimensional arrays there are used pointers as iterators while for objects of the type std::vector there are used iterators defined in this template class.

The variable `swapped` is used as a criteria whether the elements are already sorted. If there was not swapping of elements of the sequence when it was traversed then it means that the sequence is already sorted.

Take into account that the implementation you showed has undefined behavior due to this statement

```
while (begin != end-- && swapped) {
                ^^^^
```

because there is an attempt to decrement the last iterator when the range can be empty. So the implementation is incorrect.

Moreover the algorithm is not efficient. For example a tail of the array can be already sorted after some iteration of the internal loop. However in the external loop the last iterator is moved left only one position.

It is enough to use forward iterators for the bubble sort. In this case you can use the algorithm even with `std::forward_list` and others containers that do not have random access iterators.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the algorithm can be implemented using forward iterators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <forward_list>

template <typename ForwardIterator>
void bubble_sort( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last )
{
    for ( ForwardIterator sorted = first; first != last; last = sorted )
    {
        sorted = first;
        for ( ForwardIterator current = first, prev = first; ++current != last; ++prev )
        {
            if ( *current < *prev )
            {
                std::iter_swap( current, prev );
                sorted = current;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 100, 2, 56, 200, -52, 3, 99, 33, 177, -199 };

    bubble_sort( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );
    std::copy( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), 
               std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::forward_list<int> lst = { 100, 2, 56, 200, -52, 3, 99, 33, 177, -199 };

    bubble_sort( std::begin( lst ), std::end( lst ) );
    std::copy( std::begin(lst ), std::end( lst ), 
               std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

The program output is

```
-199 -52 2 3 33 56 99 100 177 200 
-199 -52 2 3 33 56 99 100 177 200
```

Here in the program there are used an array and an object of the type `std::forward_list` and the algorithm can be applied to the both containers.

Comment: if it has undefined behaviour how does it run correctly every time?

Comment: @anekix It can run for a particular case but in general will give unpredictable result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help .can you please modify your code to use slightly less variable names like `first`, `current`, `sorted` and simple like the code in question

Comment: why  ` sorted = first;` is done two time once in loop initialization and other in loop body.

Comment: @anekix These varaibels 1) allows to use the algorithm with containers that does not have forward iterators and 2) it is more efficient than the implementation you showed because it traverse the sequence only until the last swapped iterator.

Comment: if i am aasked to implement bubble sort in an interview can i use this implementation or simple loop base with indexes in array avoiding templates?also why `sorted=first` two times?

Comment: @anekix Is showed you the professionally implemented algorithm because it can be applied to a large range of containers. As you can see yourself it can be used even with the standard container std::forward_list. Try to use your own implementation with this container and you will see that there will be numerous compilation errors.

Comment: @anekix To test use my demonstrative program. Just substitute the implementation I showed for your own implementation and see what  result will be.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. i have no doubt on usefulness of you implementation. just one last que if you can clear as to why did you use two times `sorted=first` ?

Comment: is another implementation (edited in question above) any good?

Comment: @anekix In fact it is not  the bubble sort algorithm because in the bubble sort there are compared adjacent elements. And this operation j < I is defined only for random access iterators.

Answer (score 3):

The template is there simply for convenience of using the function with different types. Implementing the function to use iterators and not a simple array saves you a lot of trouble with pointers and sizes.

The `swapped` variable indicates to the algorithm that the last run from `begin` to the `end` did not result in any swaps. This means that the array is sorted already in this range (and past the `end` it's sorted as well because that's what was handled in the previous passes) and there is no need to loop until the `begin` and `end` iterator are the same. The algorithm will work if you remove this check but could result in a time waste in case of partially sorted arrays.

Let's look at this example:

```
0: {1   2   5   3   4} (begin = 0, end = 4)
1: {1   2   3   4   5} (begin = 0, end = 3)
2: {1   2   3   4   5} (begin = 0, end = 2)
3: {1   2   3   4   5} (begin = 0, end = 1)
4: {1   2   3   4   5} (begin = 0, end = 0)
```

You can see that after `0:` the array is already sorted, but without the `swapped` flag the algorithm would not break and continue checking. If the flag is there after `1:` the `swapped` flag is `false` and the algorithm quits.

Comment: as far as i know to use templates we have to intialise with the type ,something like classobject<int> obj or classobject<float> obj but here there is no initialization?

Comment: C++ [is smart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) here.